# What is the meaning of "taken from between the two collectors is"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "taken from between the two collectors is" in the following sentences?

> Like the input signal, the output signal is also balanced and since
> the collector voltages either swing in opposite directions or in the
> same direction the output voltage signal, taken from between the two
> collectors **is**, assuming a perfectly balanced circuit the zero
> difference between the two collector voltages.

(Source: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_1.html)

Does "the collector voltages either swing in opposite directions or in the same direction the output voltage signal, *taken from between the two collectors **is***" mean "the collector voltages either swing in opposite directions or in the same direction the output voltage signal *that **is*** taken from between the two collectors " ?

Is "is" inverted, omitting the relative pronoun that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the input signal, the output signal is also **balanced, and** since the collector voltages either swing in opposite directions or in the same **direction, the** output voltage signal **[no comma]** taken from between the two collectors is, assuming a perfectly balanced **circuit, the** zero difference between the two collector voltages.

The passage in the original site has several comma errors which I have corrected above; the word pairs that were missing a comma are in bold, and an unnecessary comma is removed.

The subject of that verb "is" is "the output voltage signal".

The sentence is long and   complex, and harder to understand because of the comma errors and unnecessary addtions. It is not well-written. The word "also" in the first sentence is unnecessary. The statement that the collector voltages change in the same or in different directions is pointless, since there is no information included about when those things happen.
I have rephrased it here in a sentence that I believe includes the same information:

> Like the input signal, the output signal is balanced. That output is the voltage difference between the two collectors, which will be zero if the circuit is perfectly balanced.

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing comma. I'll emphasise it with parentheses,

"The output voltage signal, taken from between the two collectors is, (assuming a perfectly balanced circuit), the zero difference between the two collector voltages." ---

In other words, "The signal **is** the zero difference between the collector voltages" –